# Clipping GeoJSON in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, clip

I am using leaflet 1.0.0 to display the GeoJSON. The GeoJSON contains data for the whole bounding box but I want to display the feature in some location only.

Is it possible to clip the GeoJSON with another GeoJSON or something like that to display on the leaflet map?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible, but it's not something that Leaflet can (or should) do.

Instead, research into other tools specialized in geoprocessing, like e.g. [`turf.js`'s `bboxClip()`](http://turfjs.org/docs/#bboxclip).

Comment: Not sure if turf's bboxclip can do but I do not want bounding box clip but rather a polygon clipping.

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/wandergis/turf-clip might work. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Biplov, wandergis/turf-clip is what you want. It's expensive though. This is what I ended up with

```
    var poly = turf.bboxPolygon(bbox);
    geojson.features=geojson.features
    .map((f)=>{
            return geojson_clip(poly,f).features
    })
    .filter((f)=>{
            return f != null && f.length > 0
    })
    .reduce((total,features)=>{
           return total=total.concat(features)
    })
```